# Tmux-powerline status-interval make flicker

Tags: tmux, powerline

Mac OSX El Capitan

Tmux 1.9a

powerline https://github.com/erikw/tmux-powerline

Sometimes the status line flash, the segments will disappear and then appeare. 
If I config the

> set-option  -g status-interval=5

it seems better but that is  not the real time status .

Is that the normal phenomenon?

Or maybe I should do some config to avoid this.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like one of your segments is doing something that takes a long time to update. You can disable segments to see if that helps ([configuration docs](http://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/master/configuration.html)). The defaults are pretty expensive, and on my older MacBook, tmux regularly sits at 5% CPU or more. Disabling `uptime` and anything else you don't need might help.

Here's an example config where I trimmed some of the fat from the right status (removed `uptime`, system load, removed the seconds from the time). This goes in 
`~/.config/powerline/themes/tmux/default.json`:

```
{
  "segments": {
    "right": [
      {
        "function": "powerline.segments.common.time.date"
      },
      {
        "function": "powerline.segments.common.time.date",
        "name": "time",
        "args": {
          "format": "%H:%M",
          "istime": true
        }
      },
      {
        "function": "powerline.segments.common.net.hostname"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The `default.json` that ships with powerline is buried in the innards of the Python package, the location of which depends on how you installed it, your Python version, and other things (e.g. mine is at `~/.virtualenv/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/config_files/themes/tmux/default.json`). You can copy that to the `~/.config` path above and modify it to your liking, or just use what I pasted.

Comment: Thank you - I had a very hard time finding how tweak to the default powerline.